# kubernetes ingress configuration

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, k3s

I have a working Nexus 3 pod, reachable on port 30080 (with NodePort): http://nexus.mydomain:30080/ works perfectly from all hosts (from the cluster or outside).

Now I'm trying to make it accessible at the port 80 (for obvious reasons).

Following the docs, I've implemented it like that (trivial):

```
[...]
---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nexus-ingress
  namespace: nexus-ns
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: nexus.mydomain
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              serviceName: nexus-service
              servicePort: 80
```

Applying it works without errors. But when I try to reach http://nexus.mydomain, I get:

> Service Unavailable

No logs are shown (the webapp is not hit).

What did I miss ?

Comment: Its local env or cloud env? How did you deploy K3s? Default Ingress Controller for K3s is `Traefik`. Did you deployed K3s with `--no-deploy-traefik`? How did you deploy Nginx Ingress Controller? As you are using annotations specific for nginx ingress and have more ingress controllers than one, you should specify in Ingress which Ingress controller should be used.

Comment: In which namespace does "nexus-service" applied? can you access http://nexus-service.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local via the nginx pods? or other pods deployed in that namespace?

Comment: @PjoterS thank you for your comment. I was not aware that Traefik was the default LB on K3s (btw, yes it has been deployed as I didn't specify ``--no-deploy-traefik``). I will try to progress by myself with that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[K3s Lightweight Kubernetes](https://www.civo.com/blog/k8s-vs-k3s#:%7E:text=K3s%20is%20a%20fully%20CNCF,apply%20against%20a%20k3s%20cluster.)

> K3s is designed to be a single binary of less than 40MB that completely implements the Kubernetes API. In order to achieve this, they removed a lot of extra drivers that didn't need to be part of the core and are easily replaced with add-ons.

As I mentioned in comments, K3s as default is using [Traefik](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/) `Ingress Controller`.

> Traefik is an open-source Edge Router that makes publishing your services a fun and easy experience. It receives requests on behalf of your system and finds out which components are responsible for handling them.

This information can be found in [K3s Rancher Documentation](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/networking/).

> Traefik is deployed by default when starting the server... To prevent `k3s` from using or overwriting the modified version, deploy `k3s` with `--no-deploy traefik` and store the modified copy in the `k3s/server/manifests` directory. For more information, refer to the official Traefik for Helm Configuration Parameters.
>
> To disable it, start each server with the `--disable traefik` option.

If you want to deploy [Nginx Ingress controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/), you can check guide [How to use NGINX ingress controller in K3s](https://dev.to/sr229/how-to-use-nginx-ingress-controller-in-k3s-2ck2).

As you are using specific `Nginx Ingress` like `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1`, you have to use `Nginx Ingress`.

If you would use more than 2 `Ingress controllers` you will need to force using `nginx ingress` by `annotation`.

```
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
```

If mention information won't help, please provide more details like your `Deployment`, `Service`.

Comment: With a few trial/errors, I was able to make it work. But still not able to use port 80 and 443. At least the service is load balanced now, it is enough for a first/personnal cluster. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can expose it on port 80 or 443 over a NodePort service or at least it is not recommended.

> In this configuration, the NGINX container remains isolated from the
> host network. As a result, it can safely bind to any port, including
> the standard HTTP ports 80 and 443. **However, due to the container
> namespace isolation, a client located outside the cluster network
> (e.g. on the public internet) is not able to access Ingress hosts
> directly on ports 80 and 443**. Instead, the external client must append
> the NodePort allocated to the `ingress-nginx` Service to HTTP requests.
>
> -- [Bare-metal considerations - NGINX Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#over-a-nodeport-service:%7E:text=In%20this%20configuration%2C%20the%20NGINX%20container,the%20ingress%2Dnginx%20Service%20to%20HTTP%20requests.)

* Emphasis added by me.

> While it may sound tempting to reconfigure the NodePort range using
> the `--service-node-port-range` API server flag to include unprivileged
> ports and be able to expose ports 80 and 443, doing so may result in
> unexpected issues including (but not limited to) the use of ports
> otherwise reserved to system daemons and the necessity to grant
> `kube-proxy` privileges it may otherwise not require.
>
> This practice is therefore **discouraged**. See the other approaches
> proposed in this page for alternatives.
>
> -- [Bare-metal considerations - NGINX Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#__code_5:%7E:text=While%20it%20may%20sound%20tempting%20to,proposed%20in%20this%20page%20for%20alternatives.)

I did a similar setup a couple of months ago. I installed a [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/) load balancer and then exposed the service. Depending on your provider (e.g., GKE), a load balancer can even be automatically spun up. So possibly you don't even have to deal with MetalLB, although MetalLB is not hard to setup and works great.